# Merging and compiling all TS files in a single JS file in Angular 2 Final

Tags: angular, typescript, gulp

Looks like things changed, so the answer for this is not applicable anymore.

Angular 2 requires to load a plenty of js files. For each component, a new JS file must be loaded. this causes delay on load and performance issues. I'm trying to achieve something similar to minifiers and mergers of others frameworks.

I'm actually trying to compile all my TS files in a single JS file and it's not working...I don't receive any error message, however It's stay stucked on "Loading...".

Well, this is my gulp file...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
gulp.task('compile_ts', function() {
 console.log('Compiling TS files...');
 var res = gulp.src('./app/**/*.ts').pipe(tsConfig());
 return res.pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "amd",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"out" : "./app/application.js"
},
"exclude": [
"node_modules" , "typings"
]
}
```

this is my systemjs.config.js

```
/**
* System configuration for Angular samples
* Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
*/
(function (global) {
System.config({
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './application.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
});
})(this);
```

It's just a simple default application...Quick Start, so I just have the app.module.ts and my app.component.ts.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: If you using any build tool (e.g. anular-cli), just enable production mode. If not you can check how angular-cli merging it on prod mode.